# What does it mean when someone says to run Django app under a subdirectory

Tags: django

I am a newbee to Django, I keep seeing in some posts `Run Django app under a subdirectory`. What does it mean? Is it like you are running a django project with various django apps in various folders? Or else is it like a new django project inside a django project, so that you can have a subdomain?

The posts I came across are 
http://askbot.org/en/question/2904/how-to-run-askbot-under-a-subdirectory/
[Run Django with URL prefix ("subdirectory") - App works, but URLs broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466708/run-django-with-url-prefix-subdirectory-app-works-but-urls-broken)
[Running a django project in a subdirectory of a site already running Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896229/running-a-django-project-in-a-subdirectory-of-a-site-already-running-drupal)

Comment: Could you give some indication of what you have done so far in terms of setting up the project, and what you are doing that causes you to see this error?

Comment: Can you give us more context on that statement? Maybe a source..?

Comment: I do not have any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this: imagine you have a website which runs in PHP/JAVA/whatever at the address http://www.example.net

The meaning of "run Django in a subdirectory" is to have access to your Django project through http://www.example.net/myDjangoWebsite without altering http://www.example.net. In that case "myDjangoWebsite/" will prefix every URL of your django project.

Comment: Can we run a separate django projects from a subdirectory of existing django project? I think hosting and integrating users of child and parent websites might be major issues. Are there any I should be thinking off?

Comment: Yes you can. You just have to tuning your web server (apache, nginx...) to redirect request to the right Django WSGI application.

Comment: How about user authentication? Can a user authenticated by parent website can access the child website?

Comment: Each Django Application instance would have separation sessions, so unless you make a system (through a middleware for example) to connect projects between them, there will no sessions sharing between them.